# How to execute a bash script task in a single machine of an AWS autoscaling group?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have recently come across a scenario where I needed to ensure only a single machine in an autoscaling group executed a given task in a bash script that was run frequently by all of them.

In short, I need some sort of leader election that avoided that two machines executed the same task that would adapt to the starting and stopping of new machines.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up implementing something that does two things:

- uses the AWS CLI (http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to find all machines that belong to the autoscaling group and select the one with the smallest ID;
- uses the EC2 instance metadata (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval) to obtain the current instance ID;
- compare the two to find out whether to run the task or not.

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  AUTOSCALING_GROUP="mygroup"

  die() { status=$1; shift; echo "FATAL: $*"; exit $status; }
  THIS_INSTANCE_ID="`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id || die \"wget instance-id has failed: $?\"`"
  LEADER_INSTANCE_ID="`aws --region us-east-1 ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:aws:autoscaling:groupName,Values=$AUTOSCALING_GROUP" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" | grep -o '\"i-[0-9a-f]\\+\"' | grep -o '[^\"]\\+' | sort | head -n 1 || die \"could not list autoscaling group instances: $?\"`"

  if [ "$THIS_INSTANCE_ID" == "$LEADER_INSTANCE_ID" ]
  then
     echo "I'm it!"
  else
     echo "I'm not it!"
  fi
  ```

This is very simple and only works because the script is run regularly on cron, and missing a few executions or having eventual multiple executions of the task is not catastrophic (just generates unnecessary cost). If you really need to synchronize to ensure only a single machine is doing the task at once, you'll need something more complex than this.

Comment: What if a "higher" (non-authority) instance is terminated and a "new lowest" (new authority) instance is spawned to replace it?

Comment: This is used in a script called regularly from cron, and for a task that will not cause a catastrophic failure if a few executions are missed. If machines are started and stopped, the next execution of the script will still only select the running machine with the lowest ID at that time.

Comment: Adding a comment to make the limitations of this approach clearer.